# Spring Integration aggregator based on content of next message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl

I have to read a file and split each line and group lines based on first column, when the first column value changes I have to release previous group. Can this be done in Spring integration DSL ?

here is how file look like, and it's sorted:

```
x 1 
x 2
x 3
y 4
y 5
y 6
```

The out put should be two messages with x =1, 2, 3 and y = 4, 5, 6.
Since this doesn't have any other relation,  regarding when message should be grouped, Can I group message as soon as I hit next non matching record ? In this case as son as I hit "y" at line number 4, group the previous "x" messages and release it ? Is it possible using custom aggregator ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to rely on the `groupTimeout()` as far as you split and aggregate in a single thread and quickly enough. So, all your records will be processed and distributed to their groups. But since we don't know how to release them, we will rely on some scheduled timeout. So, the configuration for the aggregator would be like this:

```
 .aggregate(a -> a
            .correlationExpression("payload.column1")
            .releaseStrategy(g -> false)
            .groupTimeout(1000)
            .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
            .outputProcessor(g -> {
                Collection<Message<?>> messages = g.getMessages();

                // iterate and build your output payload                                

                })
            )
```

Comment: Mean while, is there any way I can use poller to read the file, but instead of integration flow, use custom method to read line by line and group it and emit as a message ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using `.handle()` which calls your custom method for file parsing

Comment: How we can pass the file to our  custom method? Is the fileTiString transformer is the solution for that?

Comment: ??? The `FileReadingMessageSource` produces exactly messages with the `File` payload: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading. And that is already different story - should be discussed in separate thread